# Viber video trouble in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, video, viber

I have updated my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and I realize that my Viber has a little bug. When I try to view some video in group or chat it looks like transparent. See the screenshot.

[image: Viber video trouble screenshot]

Ubuntu-restricted-extras installed, the google says nothing about this trouble. Do you have any suggestions what should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this trouble. I removed totally viber through **apt** and reinstall it with **flatpak**

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

To install it I used the command:

```
flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
```

To run:

```
flatpak run com.viber.Viber
```

The trouble disappeared.